# Python Manchine Learning for content based Recommendation system using cosine similarities

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am building content based recommendation system. I have done count vectorization, the vectors are

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features=5000,stop_words='english')
newdata = newdata.dropna(subset=['tags'])
movievector = cv.fit_transform(newdata['tags']).toarray()
movievector

 -----------The array from moviecector are:  array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)

movievector.shape

-----------and the shape is (4806, 5000)
```

I am not using any libraries for calculating cosine similarity. And according to the rule of my project, I cannot use the library in this part. I need to use pure python code.

I am not able to take any two random vectors to calculate the cosine similarities to recommend the movies.
Help me to pass two random vectors in the plain python code so that cosine similarities can be calculated and I can recommend the movie.

```
import requests
from math import sqrt

def cosine_similarity(item1, item2):
    dot_product = 0
    norm1 = 0
    norm2 = 0

    for key in item1:
        if key in item2:
            dot_product += item1[key] * item2[key]
    
    for key in item1:
        norm1 += item1[key] ** 2
    for key in item2:
        norm2 += item2[key] ** 2

    return dot_product / (sqrt(norm1) * sqrt(norm2))

def generate_recommendations(item_id):
    response = requests.get('/api/items')
    items = response.json()

    selected_item = next(item for item in items if item['id'] == item_id)

    similarities = [{'item': item, 'similarity': cosine_similarity(selected_item, item)} for item in items]

    sorted_similarities = sorted(similarities, key=lambda x: x['similarity'], reverse=True)

    recommendations = sorted_similarities[:5]

    return recommendations
```

I tried different ways but failed to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? Can you clearly mention what help you require?

Comment: I am not able to take any two random vectors to calculate the cosine similarities to recommend the movies.
Help me to pass two random vectors in the plain python code so that cosine similarities can be calculated and I can recommend the movie

Comment: can you add how does `selected_item` look/print like? is it a dict with a key as 'id' and some 'value'?

Comment: to pass a random vector you can use `numpy` library. By doing `numpy.random.random((10))` you can get a random vector of size 10. Add this to your `selected_item[value]` and `item[value]` to check if your function is correct or not.